# Number of Execution Contexts during Callouts

Tags: trigger, callout, rest, executioncontext

I am trying to understand how execution context works with respect to callouts.

**Use case :** Whenever an Account's status is updated to "Ready for Integration", a REST callout will happen towards an external system. 
           After getting a successful handshake, the account's status will be set to "Integration Successful"

Am I right in assuming the number of execution contexts that will be created for the following use case  ?

[image]

Comment: 2-4 are the same context. so 2 context (transactions) total

Comment: All the asynch/future operations and anything arising from those ops will be in a separate execution context right ?...tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST Transaction**

The account is updated, triggers and workflows fire, future method queued

**Second Transaction**

Future method executes
Makes callout and receives response (Synchronously with the future method unless you have some other integration where the external system calls back in)

Account is updated, triggers and workflows fire when the response is received and the code in your future method updates the account with the results